# Sharepoint Crawler is denied access to sites

Tags: sharepoint, search, web-crawler

We create all our site collections programatically with a custom site def/template. Everything works as expected, except for the crawler. It's apparently denied access to the sites. The crawl logs says:

> http://server.localnetwork.lan/somesites/siteName
>   The object was not found. (The item
>   was deleted because it was either not
>   found or the crawler was denied access
>   to it.)

And in the log files I'm getting this:

> 08/11/2009 14:20:34.01    OWSTIMER.EXE
>   (0x0674)
>     0x1560  Search Server Common
>     MS Search Administration
>     7hmh    High        exception in
>   SearchUpgradeProvisioner Keyword
>   Config
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   jobServerSearchServiceInstance is null
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchUpgradeProvisioner..ctor(SearchServiceInstance
>   searchServiceInstance)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.OSSPrimaryGathererProject.ProvisionContentSources()

If I create a site collection manually the crawler is able to access it. The same users/accounts have the same access on both sites, so that shouldn't be the issue.

The code we use to actually create the site collection looks a little like this:

```
SPWebApplication app = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("WebApplicationUrl"));
app.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
app.Sites.Add("url", "title", "description", "language code", "SiteTemplateName", "Owner.Username", "Owner.Fullname", "Owner.Email");
app.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;
```

The code has been slightly altered to protect the innocent... ;)

Any idea what we're doing wrong?

(Please note, I'm not sure if this is a programming error or a config/setup error, so I'm cross-posting with Stackoverflow)

Comment: When you create the site collections by hand, is it in the same managed path as when you create them through code? Also, do you have any custom crawl rules setup that might affect the situation?

Comment: Yes, same managed path. No custom crawl rules at all.

Comment: A few other questions - have you tried creating a site programmatically, but with a standard SharePoint template instead of a custom template? When you create the sites by hand, are they with the custom template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260095/sharepoint-crawler-is-denied-access-to-sites/1264559#1264559)

Comment: Any idea why your hand created sites were working, but not the programmatic ones? I've seen this error before, but didn't suggest it because it typically causes all crawls to fail.

Comment: I have no idea... It appears to work now, so we're happy... ;)